Dimensions and coordinates don't match up
We can see here that the object has a Z dimension of 2.44m, its origin thus being at 1.22m since it's bottom face is resting on the plane of 0:0:0 :

However when I select a bottom point, it shows its local coordinates to have a Z of -1.2383m instead of the expected 1.22m. How is that possible, and how do I fix it ? I need to be precise to 0.005 (half a centimeter). Thanks !


Damn, I copy-pasted the entire question into chatgpt and it told me to "apply the scale" with ctrl+a and it actually solved it. This is a strange way of doing things, so how can I avoid this step in the future ? If I make a change to dimensions, it should be considered to be applied immediately ?

Every time you "scale" an object, it doesn't "change", it's shown different. You can see above the dimensions that your object has scales different from 1. (And a huge problem with scale X = 0).  If you want to rely on the original sizes of the object, the scales must be 1 (that's what "apply scale" does, it forces the scale to change your original object and reset the scale to 1)

One not-so-obvious point is that scale represents deformations. You can use it the way you want, but scale will always be a deformation of the base mesh. If you let it be 1 and only change the shape in edit mode, you'll never have issue with all the things that depends on the scale.

Okay but every time I change the dimensions, the scale changes. I'd love for it to stay one but Blender changes it itself.

@ouai As Lutzi said, change it in Edit Mode if you do not want the scale to change to something other than 1. What you enter in the value fields there are transformations (that's why it says Transform above it), not edits of the underlying mesh geometry. Those transformations are moving the object to a different location, rotating it or deforming it by resizing per one or more axes. The dimensions are there on the one hand to inform you what the current dimensions are and are a way to resize it without having to calculate a scaling factor - but converting it to that factor afterwards.
